# The "link" link when clicked redirects to a page that immediately redirects back to a different URL

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, permalink

Try with this question, for example. Click link and you'll be redirected back to a different URL again.

This means that the only way to get the link you are supposed to share a question or post with is to right click it and select "copy URL" or similar.

The problem with that is that not everyone knows you can or have to do this, especially the non-SO crowd.

Comment: An auto copy to your clipboard w a box opening up showing the short url... the way bit.ly works for example, would be great when clicking the "link" for a short permalink.

Comment: @peter there is no way to "auto copy to clipboard" without using Flash or another browser plugin

Comment: @Jeff - Thanks. Wasn't aware of that. I just looked at bit.ly again, and they do in fact use Flash for the copy to clipboard part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why those users are expected to use the twitter and facebook icons (which also use the shortened referral URLs)

[image]

**The link function is for more advanced users who understand how to copy a link.**

Comment: I hope that last sentence is sarcasm, because it's funny.  Otherwise, I hope you are seriously underestimating your users.

Comment: You are forgetting about all the technically inexperienced bloggers, for one. Now they can't get the proper link (the one that they will give them credit) since there is no blog button.